# Producing custom shaped PDF format (like A4,A5 but custom)

Tags: formatting, geometry

In the preamble, I can set the format of the PDF file via the geometry package as I want (here 5cmx20cm).

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,german]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault,condensed,light]{roboto}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=50 mm,paperheight=200 mm,textheight=0mm,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm]{geometry}
```

I am trying to produce a custom shaped PDF like

```
                    15cmx20cm - circle 3cm radius at (10,10)
```

**Like this:**

50mm x 200mm

[image]

150mm x 80mm

[image]

My goal: 150mm x 200mm minus the red circle

[image]

Is it possible to do?

Comment: The media box is a rectangle. If you want a hole, don't put color there (and hope that the pdf viewer lets the background through).

Comment: Im not putting this picture into my PDF file. This is just as an example.
I need that the output PDF file is (A4 minus custom shape).